# Can't see table columns DbVisualizer Graph PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, graph, dbvisualizer

I'm trying to make a graph with all the TABLES/VIEWS that I want :
`pg_authid`, `pg_group`, `pg_roles`, `pg_auth_members`, `pg_namespace`, `pg_shadow`, `pg_user`.

So as you can see it only works for TABLES columns `pg_authid`, `pg_auth_members`, `pg_namespace`.
But not for the VIEWS columns `pg_group`, `pg_roles`, `pg_shadow`, `pg_user`.
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/40/5/1570177040-capture14.png

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: If you open (double-click) one of the pg_group, pg_roles, pg_shadow, pg_user and check the Columns tab, does it then show the columns? For further assistance please use the Help->Contact Support in DbVisualizer and post a support request. That will help the DbVisualizer team to understand your setup.

Comment: Yes @roger when I open one of those, I can see the columns, but not on the graph...

Comment: For further assistance please use the Help->Contact Support in DbVisualizer and post a support request.